# Foreach inside of a foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I need help with a foreach within a foreach.  I'm using the Wordpress plug-in, Advanced Custom Fields to create Repeater Fields inside of repeater fields. I'm then displaying (or attempting to display) them on the frontend outside the main loop using the code below:

```
 <?php
            //Loop Through Days and Sights
              $days = get_field('day_and_highlights');
              $n = 0;

              if($days){
                echo '<div>';
                  foreach($days as $day){ 
                    $n++;
                    echo '<h2> Day ' . $n . ': ' . $day['destination_dropdown'] . '</h2><br/>';
                    //Loop through Attractions
                    <?php
                    $attractions = get_field('attraction_list');
                    if($attractions){
                        echo '<ul class=\"list_attractions\">';
                        foreach($attractions as $attraction){
                            echo '<li class=\"single_attraction\"><p>' . $attraction['add_attraction'] . '</p></li>';
                        }; //end foreach
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }; //endif 
                  };
                echo '</div>';
              };
            ?>
```

The first foreach echo's everything spot on.  The inner foreach doesn't do jack.  I can't get it to do anything.

Comment: did you print_r($attractions)?

Comment: No, but I did now.  Nothing happened.  What was I trying to accomplish?

Comment: as you are iterating over an array ... its nice to know whats inside your array you are interating. if the array is empty its normal that nothing is happening. print_r prints the array content. continue reading here > http://www.php.net/print_r

Comment: Thanks Jan.  So coincidentally, when I print_r($days), i get this

Comment: 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [destination_dropdown] => Florence, Italy [attraction_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [add_attraction] => (Rome) Colosseum ) [1] => Array ( [add_attraction] => (Rome) Colosseum ) [2] => Array ( [add_attraction] => (Rome) Colosseum ) etc...'  So all the values are in the first array?  So confused.

Comment: What's in the `$attractions` array?  Put a `print_r($attractions)` in a new line immediately after `$attractions = get_field('attraction_list');` and prior to `if($attractions){`

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra php tag:

```
             //Loop through Attractions
             <?php
                $attractions = get_field('attraction_list');
                if($attractions){
```

Try removing it.

Also, your IF and FOREACH statements should not end in semicolons:

```
                }; //endif
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Yea, I was playing with alternative options, I think I forgot to remove that before I pasted my code in here.  I'll remove, but I don't think that'll fix anything.

Comment: Yea, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you, genuinely.  I won't do that from now on.  I actually don't know why I started in the first place.